# Indeterminant form in a limit

Tags: limits

If, after evaluating a limit we get an indeterminant, of the form $\dfrac{-1}{0}$, how do we conclude whether it converges to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$? Just because it is negative, how can we conclude for sure that it will tend to $-\infty$?

Please refer to the following picture for the original question

[image: please refer to the following picture for the original question]

After evaluating this I have an indeterminant of the form $\dfrac{-1}{0}$

Comment: can you give us the term of your Limit?

Comment: I just uploaded a picture of the question

Comment: There is no general answer "how do we conclude" a limit of $\pm \infty$, and it is possible there would be neither of these limits.  You've been around awhile, so I think you should learn about using $\LaTeX$ and MathJax to post mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't. Take, for instance, the limits$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x-1}{-x}\text{ and }\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x-1}x.$$In both cases, we have a limit of the type that you mentioned. But the first limit is $+\infty$, whereas the second one is $-\infty$.

Comment: So we can not determine whether it tends to infinity or negative infinity?

Comment: @Aditi Just using the information that you provided, no, we can't. It's worst than that: the limit may not exist.

Comment: Okay thank you ! I was confused because I had four options to choose from among which two were infinity and negative infinity.

Answer (score 1):

write your term in the form
$$\frac{x^3(-1+\frac{8}{x^3})}{x^2(2+\frac{5}{x}+\frac{7}{x^2})}$$
from here we get
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}x\cdot \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-1+\frac{8}{x^2}}{2+\frac{5}{x}+\frac{7}{x^2}}$$
and you will get $$\infty\cdot (-\frac{1}{2})=-\infty$$

Comment: Exactly what I did . Then I will get infinity multiplied by negative half on solving with the limit. How do I determine whether it tends to infinity or negative infinity

Comment: But is it possible to multiple numbers with infinity ?

Comment: I’m sorry but I’ve never used such a concept till now

Comment: yes it is possible, $$(-1)\infty=-\infty$$

Comment: And I’m also confused over whether it is possible to directly substitute in $x$ if it was not determined ?

Answer (score 1):

It is case by case:

suppose we have $f(x)=\frac{-1}{x^2}$,in that case we know that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)\to -\infty$, Because $\forall x\in\Bbb R ,\,x^2>0$.

But for example $f(x)=\frac{-1}{x}$ we can't say anything, because the left side limit(the limit as $x$ goes to $0$ from the "negative"(left side) side) is $\infty$ and the right side limit is $-\infty$.